# There is a web standard for animated vector images?

Tags: animation, svg, web-standards

Assuming that the SVG is the standard for still vector images, there is an equivalent for animated vector-based images too ?

The problem I'm trying to solve can't be solved by pixel-based formats such as APNG or GIF, they don't scale at all on different displays, and they also get really really heavy pretty quick, vector images are what I need but I need a standard way to provide a file with an animated vector entities in it.

To be clear I'm not trying to animate a webpage or part of it, I'm asking for a filetype or standard that is good for just this task.

Comment: SVG can be animated using SMIL, CSS or javascript. There are plenty of examples out there if your search for them.

Comment: CSS or JS don't fit my case and requirements, SMIL is probably the technical and more precise description for what @scunliffe said and I'm thankful that someone mentioned this term so I can finally discover more about how to animate an SVG. You should probably post an answer about SMIL son I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG specification includes [SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) as an animation mechanism. IE9/10/11 do not support SMIL, although other UAs do. There's a javascript library called [fakesmile](http://leunen.me/fakesmile/) that can enable SMIL on UAs for which support is lacking.

There's also CSS animations which IE does support, although overall support for CSS animations is somewhat less complete in most UAs.

Answer (score 3):

You can animate SVG graphics... they don't have to be static.  That said, SVG is the only vector graphics format the web supports (natively) so I guess the answer is SVG! ;-)

Comment: maybe I don't know the right entities for that, can you give an example ? I really have never encountered an animated SVG in my history on the internet.

Comment: @Toast no thanks, as I said, only something provided by a file format or a standard approach.

Comment: If you look in the right column of this page (Related) you'll see all kinds of questions about this.  It is actually fairly easy and was part of the design of SVG to be adaptable via style, scale, transformation, translation, etc. Here's a great example: http://svg-whiz.com/svg/linguistics/theCreepyMouth.svg

Comment: @scunliffe right now the only things that I found are pages and pages of cryptic javascript code mixed with some svg or CSS, that's why I'm still skeptical about the SVG potential, if this is true it means that a lot of web developers should take a better look at how things work.

Comment: Getting SVG to become a spec supported by all browsers properly took years... as a result the chances of another vector graphic format coming along and replacing it on the web is both highly unlikely but also would take another 5+ years to become a standard. So you're stuck with SVG. That said, this isn't a bad thing! Everything in SVG can be animated... you just need to apply the math to it or use a library that does it for you. To be honest I've found "Raphael" to be quite handy for this http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html and as a bonus it falls back to VML in old IE that didn't support SVG

Comment: @scunliffe my point is also about using this animations on desktop and places other then the "web" or my browser, my point is packing everything together and be sure that a given standard will make my animation work as expected; I also noticed Raphael before, but since it's JS I discarded that, I have one doubt now that you bring this up: Raphael can generate plain SVG file from my JS sources ?

Comment: SVG is the only vector format that works on the Web... but the content is an XML document http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html that contains all the elements in your graphic.  You can render your SVG in a WebView in a desktop app, or in various controls (depending on the environment... typically as a static image). Since SVG is a "Web Format" it was intentionally designed to be stylable with CSS and editable (or even created entirely) with JavaScript. Since SVG is XML - you can save any generated content back to a file if desired.

Comment: yes but the substantial difference is that an SVG ( just XML without JS or CSS ) is a self-contained environment, where something using a third part JS library it's probably not, that's why I would like to just have everything I need in 1 file and ship it like that.